# How to check when the document has started loading, document.readyState is not updated

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, dom-events

When clicking a link in Firefox 10, the `document.readyState == 'complete'` until the request from the server actually returns.

Is there a cross-browser way to check if there is a request in progress or not by looking at the current document?

Comment: Is this clicking a link to go to a new page?  If so, a new document is created to load the page into so you won't ever see a status change on the current document other than an onunload handler.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case. Aha, so I can register events on the onunload, perfect then. Please add a comment so I can approve it and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this clicking a link is going to a new page, a new document is created to load the page into so you won't ever see a status change on the current document other than an onunload handler.

You can see when your document is being unloaded with [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload).  There are some browser differences in implementation as this is not a standard's-backed feature, but it does work in modern browsers.